# Invoke a FM instead of workflow for business event

Tags: workflow, abap

Can you please tell me how to invoke a FM for a BUS object using events? Is it Mandatory to have Workflow associated with the event.

As per blogs for Business events, they talk about linking to workflow task or workflow. But I don't need workflow, instead thinking if we can just invoke a FM?

I want the FM to be executed whenever a business object gets changed.

Comment: Please explain why you want to use a `Workflow Event` to trigger something if the action is not related to the workflow. If it's not related to the workflow, either use a user exit, or the enhancement framework. If you want to trigger something based on a `Change Document` then you may link it to a workflow event, which triggers one task for instance (it's like a workflow with one step, which starts and ends in an instant, I don't see why it's a problem to use it this way). Please, add context to the question so that we can help you better.

Comment: Question also asked in [SCN](https://answers.sap.com/questions/12705809/invoke-abap-fm-or-class-using-bor-event.html)

Comment: Hi, Can you please let me know when would the FM defined here gets triggered ?  Just before DB commit or after ?

Comment: Hi Sandra, I need to trigger IDocs whenever Qual Notif gets changed (QM02) immediately. So i am thinking that it would be nice idea to trigger just after changes are committed so that I could read the values from DB table to trigger. Regarding User-Exit, as the values would not yet be committed, i am not sure if we can trigger from there. Also we need to send some additional long text data, which would not be available at the userexit/badi. So I think userexit would not be the right place.

Comment: Just curious if like this https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/Snippets/Trigger+a+Business+Object+Event, just invoke a FM which could triggers IDoc instead of some workflow processing  ?

Comment: divScorp proposed a good solution to trigger your code without triggering any task/workflow

Answer (score 2):

In SWE2 T-code, You can create linkage between your business object and event. Follow the below step -

1. In Object type provide your Business object and choose your event.
2. Select receiver call as Function module and in receiver FM, provide your FM which you want to trigger.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: When would the FM defined here gets triggered ?  just after db commit or before ?

Comment: Just curious if like this https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/Snippets/Trigger+a+Business+Object+Event , just invoke a FM which could triggers IDoc instead of some workflow processing ?

Comment: i could raise the event in SWUE. But the same not happening via standard transaction - QM02. Does this mean, i have to manually invoke the event ?

Comment: @kjyothiraditya Turn on event trace with SWELS, after that save anything via QM02 , Check whether the event trigger in SWEL. Otherwise, you've to created the event 'Changed' for QM02.

Comment: I did that, but no trace was there